# How to get the context of the request url in nginx.conf?

Tags: nginx

Suppose that the request url is:

http://ip:port/**myapp**/user/add

How can I get "**myapp**" in nginx.conf ?

I know /myapp/user/add can be got by using variable **$request_uri**, but I can't find about the variable that obtains the context of the url.

Many thanks.

Comment: It depends on how you intend to use it. Normally you would define a location block (e.g. `location /myapp/ { ... }`) which would handle all URIs that begin with `/myapp/`.

Comment: @RichardSmith My location must be defined as  /, so what I want is to get the context from request URL in the location block. e.g.  URL is http://ip/myapp/useradd, context is myapp, that is what I need.

Comment: Any of the directives that support regular expressions can be used for your purposes, but without more information, I cannot suggest which one would suit your requirements.